# how can I randomize the steps order of Cucumber?

Tags: testing, random, cucumber, scenarios

How can I randomize the fastest method /way to do?:

```
 Scenario Outline: As an Piet i can delete users
    Given the user is logged in as 'Piet'
    Given the menu item 'user management' is selected
    When the user '<username>' is deleted
    Then the notification panel contains the message 'Deze gebruiker is 
  succesvol verwijderd.'
    And the notification panel contains no errors

#randomize order of delete

    Examples: User accounts to delete
      | username      |
      | hans          |
      | piet          |
      | kees          |
      | jan           |
```

I expected Cucumber to support something like this:
(but apparently it doesn't , at least not yet)

```
 Scenario Outline: As an Piet i can delete users
    Given the user is logged in as 'PIET'
    Given the menu item 'user management' is selected
    When the user '<username>' is deleted
    Then the notification panel contains the message 'Deze gebruiker is 
 verwijderd.'
    And the notification contains no errors

#randomize order of delete

    Examples: User accounts to delete
      | username [RANDOM] |
      | hans              |
      | piet              |
      | kees              |
      | jan               |
```

so what is the best way to get these steps run in a random order?

Comment: Which prog language are u using?

Comment: i'm using Java...

Answer (score 0):

```
Scenario Outline: As an Piet i can delete users
  Given there are <users_left> users for deletion
  And the user is logged in as 'PIET'
  And the menu item 'user management' is selected
  When a user is deleted
  Then the notification panel contains the message 'Deze gebruiker is verwijderd.'
  And the notification contains no errors

 Examples: User accounts left to delete
  | users_left |
  | 4          |
  | 3          |
  | 2          |
  | 1          |
```

Using this method, you ensure that there are users to delete, and then you simply delete a random user within the step `a user is deleted`

Comment: How are the user account to be deleted passed onto the scenario?

Comment: There should be a world object if you are using JS, Ruby or Java, so you can attach your users for deletion in a before hook. Reading these users in your step, you can pick one at random to delete in your step, and loop over, deleting a user and removing them from the array each time. (Recommend checking if the array exists, and if it doesn't, create it, ensuring that you don't attempt to delete the same user twice).

Comment: that's not exactly what I mean Grasshopper.... i guess random can't be done with scenario outline. It would be a great feature of Cucumber though

Comment: Random cannot be achieved with a scenario outline as you want it, as logic isn't in place in the feature files, however, random can be achieved if you move the logic to the step definition, which is what I'm suggesting in my answer.

Comment: It would be great if it could be done from scenario outline

Comment: The way that they could implement it would be in some form of "Shuffle Mode" for the suite, rather than for any specific scenario, where it breaks down the suite into all scenarios, shuffles it, and then runs it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to prove here? If you can delete a user do you really need to waste valuable runtime deleting other users? Why not simplify and make things easier, perhaps with

```
Given Fred is registered
And I am logged in and can delete users
When I delete user Fred
Then I should see Fred has been deleted
```

Cucumber scenarios are meant to be simple and to help develop behaviour. They are not designed to be used for randomising, or doing extensive testing. If you want to do that write a unit test, it should be cheaper and faster.